# How to run smartctl as root without switching to root?

Tags: root, c, non-root-user, privileges, capabilities

I have this C code that runs `smartctl` command and takes its output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello ! " << endl;
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1035];

    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen("smartctl -A /dev/sda", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. */
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path), fp) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", path);
    }

    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The machine is openSUSE 13.2. My problem is it requires root privilege, but I don't want to switch to root.

What I tried and did not work:

1. Added `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability to the program executable.
2. Added `CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE` to the `smartctl` executable (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828216/what-linux-capability-to-use-with-popen-call-and-smartctl-command-line?noredirect=1#comment45932390_28828216)) and I also added it to the program executable.
3. I used `setcap 'cap_dac_override=+ep' cpptest` to add the capability (also for the `CAP_SYS_Admin`) but when I use `getcap` I get only one of them, not both. (Can you help me in this ?)
4. I changed the permission of `/dev/sda` to 755, 777, 766 and changed ownership of the device to my group using `chown root:users /dev/sda`.

I wrote a program that performs some network operations using sockets and it required root privilege but I added `CAP_NET_ADMIN` and it worked. I just don't know why capabilities does not work.

This is really important issue. Any help is really appreciated.

Please note: I provided a C code but this is an issue with Linux not a programming problem.

Comment: I wonder would it help if you changed your executable owner to `root:users` and set SUID bit?

Comment: Using `chown root:users cpptest` ?

Comment: Yes, and then `chmod u+s cpptest`

Comment: No it did not work. I get `sh: smartctl: command not found`

Comment: How is it supposed to find your `smartctl` if it's not in your current directory?

Comment: You could try like `PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH ./cpptest`

Comment: I changed it to `/usr/sbin/smartctl`, the message is gone but I do not get the output after the operation.

Comment: I think I must recall my comment about SUID bit after I've read this guidance http://www.onlamp.com/excerpt/PUIS3_chap16/index3.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21629/discussion-between-3bdalla-and-uvv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/smartmontools/mailman/smartmontools-support/thread/559247260611071125x2fb9d6b8s72e08f62281f560f%40mail.gmail.com/#msg10779728) discussion `CAP_SYS_RAWIO` capability needs to be applied to `smartctl` executable.

Comment: You have my respect! Thanks for the help! :D